# iOS- Initializing Custom Class with JSON returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this line in my code,

```
Country *country = [[Country alloc] initWithNSDictionary:jsonObject];
```

I am getting one element in **jsonObject** but why **country** in nil?

I have Country class file in project and I have make a object of it by this.

**JSON response:**

```
{"geonames": [{
  "continent": "AS",
  "capital": "Nuova Delhi",
  "languages": "en-IN,hi,bn,te,mr,ta,ur,gu,kn,ml,or,pa,as,bh,sat,ks,ne,sd,kok,doi,mni,sit,sa,fr,lus,inc",
  "geonameId": 1269750,
  "south": 6.747139,
  "isoAlpha3": "IND",
  "north": 35.504223,
  "fipsCode": "IN",
  "population": "1173108018",
  "east": 97.403305,
  "isoNumeric": "356",
  "areaInSqKm": "3287590.0",
  "countryCode": "IN",
  "west": 68.186691,
  "countryName": "India",
  "continentName": "Asia",
  "currencyCode": "INR"
}]}
```

`initWithNSDictionary` method

```
- (instancetype) initWithNSDictionary:(NSDictionary*)countryInfo_
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        NSLog(@"Country Info = %@",countryInfo_);
        self.code = [countryInfo_  valueForKey:@"countryCode"];
        self.name = [countryInfo_  valueForKey:@"countryName"];
        self.continent = [countryInfo_  valueForKey:@"continentName"];
        self.region = [countryInfo_  valueForKey:@"region"];
        self.currencyCode = [countryInfo_  valueForKey:@"currencyCode"];
        self.population = [countryInfo_  valueForKey:@"population"];

    }
    NSLog(@"code %@", code);

    return self;
}
```

Comment: add `initWithNSDictionary` method in the question. Second thing change your question's title. It should be related to your query or issue!!

Comment: changed title. Do you have the solution? @KetanParmar

Comment: What your `initWithNSDictionary` mehod do? According to that anyone can give answer!!

Comment: @KahanR Is `jsonObject` contain this response?

Comment: Are you trying to allocate your country object with dictionary?

Comment: Yes country object with dictionary.  @SMi

Comment: @KAR You aren't really helping yourself by not providing requested data. As Ketan Already asked you, your `initWithDictionary` method is the key to resolving this issue. Unless you add it, there is no way for anyone to find your bug

Comment: I have added method of initWithNSDictionary method @NSNoob

Comment: @KAR See your bug is identified right when you posted it. Your JSON structure is Dict->Array->Dict. You first need to reach the innermost Dict to use Value for Keys like @"countryCode" etc. But since you haven't, you get nil as result because your outermost dict has no values against those keys

Comment: Do you understand what I said or do you need further explanation of your bug?

Comment: That dictionary contains a top-level `geonames` entry containing an array of dictionaries.  Which one of the array elements do you want to use?  Always the first one?  If so, that doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: yes, need further explanation of my bug @NSNoob

Comment: @KAR Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the line of code to

```
Country *country = [[Country alloc] initWithNSDictionary:(NSDictionary *)jsonObject];
```

and for access variable from Country Use

```
[countryCode setText:[country.code description]];
```

This solved my problem by using description.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't provide sufficient information in question, I am writing answer on basis of assumption:

In your `Country` class `initWithNSDictionary` method should define something like this.

```
  -(instancetype)initWithNSDictionary : (NSDictionary*)dictionary{

self = [super init];

if (self) {

    self.firstName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"firstName"];  //This is just example because you haven't add sufficient information in question
    self.lastName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"lastName"];
}

return self;
}
```

Then you can create instance or object of `Country` as you have created in your question,

```
 Country *country = [[Country alloc] initWithNSDictionary:jsonObject];
```

Make sure that json object have key and value that you have used in `initWithNSDictionary` method. I have just give example of firstname and lastname. You should manage data in `initWithNSDictionary` as per your json object.

Comment: He has added the `initWithDictionary` method now, check it out

Comment: Why are you using `valueForKey:`?

Comment: His bug is that he is not extracting the innermost dict from his JSON (dict->arr->dict model) which is why his value extraction returns nil. Show him how to get the innermost dict and your answer will be completed. And of course, what Droppy said

Comment: @Droppy : I have provide just example based on assumption!

Comment: Sorry that's the wrong answer.  Use `objectForKey:` or `dictionary[key]` form.

Comment: @NSNoob : Yeah! you're right but i am not clear that he is passing innermost dictionary to initWith method or outermost. So, it is better to keep answer as it is as example.

Answer (score 1):

Your Structure is:

```
-Dictionary
--Array
---Dictionary
```

This means you have a top dictionary which contains an array of Dictionaries.

Your bug is, that you are trying to initialize your object with the Top Level dictionary which has no keys against the values that you are mentioning, therefore it returns nil and your object has nil values in turn.

To put it simply, you are passing the dictionary which has only the following key and value pair:

```
Key: Geonames
Value: An Array
```

Then in your init method you are assuming it contains other keys when in fact those other keys exist only in the dictionary enclosed in the array. Which is the following dict:

```
{
  "continent": "AS",
  "capital": "Nuova Delhi",
  "languages": "en-IN,hi,bn,te,mr,ta,ur,gu,kn,ml,or,pa,as,bh,sat,ks,ne,sd,kok,doi,mni,sit,sa,fr,lus,inc",
  "geonameId": 1269750,
  "south": 6.747139,
  "isoAlpha3": "IND",
  "north": 35.504223,
  "fipsCode": "IN",
  "population": "1173108018",
  "east": 97.403305,
  "isoNumeric": "356",
  "areaInSqKm": "3287590.0",
  "countryCode": "IN",
  "west": 68.186691,
  "countryName": "India",
  "continentName": "Asia",
  "currencyCode": "INR"
}
```

So you need to get the Dictionary mentioned above from the array and use it to initialize your object.

To fix it, you need to modify your `initWithDictionary` method (Or ideally, the way you call your initWithdictionary method but lets forget that for now).

```
- (instancetype) initWithNSDictionary:(NSDictionary*)countryInfo_
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        NSLog(@"Country Info = %@",countryInfo_);
        NSArray *internalArray = countryInfo_[@"geonames"]; //Now you got your array of dictionaries.
        if([internalArray count]>0){
            NSDictionary *internalDictionary = internalArray[0]; //Assuming there will always be only one dictionary in that array but if there are more, thats your design problem. You got your internal dictionary now
            self.code = internalDictionary[@"countryCode"];
            self.name = internalDictionary[@"countryName"];
            self.continent = internalDictionary[@"continentName"];
            self.region = internalDictionary[@"region"];
            self.currencyCode = internalDictionary[@"currencyCode"];
            self.population = internalDictionary[@"population"];
        }


    }
    NSLog(@"code %@", code);

    return self;
}
```

**NOTE:** This is with the assumption that there will always be one dictionary in your arrays of dictionary or at least just the first one which you would like to use. This means there is some info you have withheld from us or a really big design flaw on your end.

Comment: Why are you allocating `internalDictionary` rather than referring the existing one in the array?

Comment: @Droppy I like it that way. It can be simply accessed by `[internalArray objectAtIndex:0]`. See the edit history, I just wrote that initially but don't really like it. Kinda makes me feel unsafe

Comment: But meh yeah instead of being paranoid, it is really wasting an instance so gonna revert back to that

Comment: While you're doing that then, use the newer Objective-C literal format; `x = array[0]` and `x = dict[key]` as it's much easier to type and read.

Comment: Also you missed the similar `internalArray` `initWithArray` nonsense.

Comment: @Droppy Sadly not much as when I stepped into iOS dev ARC was fully kicked in and handled all the retain and release stuff. Also, You are very welcome to add your own solution. And seeing one of your comment on OP's question, I would suggest you take a reading of Be-nice policy of SO.

Comment: Yeah you are right about being nice, but I have since removed that comment and find it frustrating with the level of competence of the people on this site now.  If someone cannot understand the structure of a JSON file then they simply should not be programming.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Country *country = [[Country alloc] initWithNSDictionary:[jsonObject objectForKey:@"your key"]];

//[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    //jsonObject ?: [NSNull null], @"jsonObject",nil]
```

Comment: this is my jsonObject -  jsonObject(
        {
        areaInSqKm = "3287590.0";
        capital = "Nuova Delhi";
        continent = AS;
        continentName = Asia;
        countryCode = IN;
        countryName = India;
        currencyCode = INR;
        east = "97.403305";
        fipsCode = IN;
        geonameId = 1269750;
        isoAlpha3 = IND;
        isoNumeric = 356;
        north = "35.504223";
        population = 1173108018;
        south = "6.747139";
        west = "68.186691";
    }
)  @SMi

Comment: @KahanR Please add response of api in your question not comment.

Comment: If you want to init your Country object's attribute with jsonObject's values then you have to insert each value to those attributes through keys

Comment: The top level available key points to an array Value which contains a dictionary at 0 index so for your answer to work, the user will also have to specify index.